# QGIS - many to many relations - query expression

Tags: qgis, relation, many-to-many

I have a polygon layer with area geometries of parcels and tables with contracts, with owners / users linked by means of a link table in many to many relationships. This is because some parcels may have multiple owners and each owner may have multiple and different contracts to certain parcels.
Can I, and if so how, do a query of a related layer/table in the expression editor or define a style so that I query attributes of a related table? For example, I would like to know or display how many parcels of a particular owner already have contracts. What is the correct expression for querying a value of another realted layer?

my exemplatory set up:

*table: owner*

| fid | owner |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Miller |
| 2 | Andrews |
| 3 | ... |

*table: contracts*

| fid | contract |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 20230901 (Hyperlink) |
| 2 | 20190628 (Hyperlink) |
| 3 | ... |

*polygon: parcels*

| fid | parcel |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | parcel 23 |
| 2 | parcel 44/6 |
| 3 | parcel 789 |
| 4 | ... |

*link table: links*

| fid | parcel | owner | contract |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | ... | ... | ... |

Comment: sorry for the display of the tables. in edit mode it looks fine :/

Comment: the table requires a blank line before it

Comment: Is writing SQL an option for you? QGIS can compile and execute the *SQLite/SpatiaLite* dialect and functionality on most data sources narively. Use a *Virtual Layer* (from the *Layer* menu or from within the *DB Manager*) and creaate thematic layers as needed.

Comment: if there is no other , sure it would be an option. I've never done this before, so i am quite unfamiliar with the procedure...

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? It seems like the information you want is already in the links table.  If you query the links table for owner 2, you would get parcels 1 & 3 both under contract 2.  Do you want a table that has the actual owner name, parcel number and contract number/link?  For example, if you query for owner miller, you would get parcels 23 & 44/6 both under contract 20190628?

Comment: yes, my problem is, if I start a search by attribute in the link table the results do not affect the layer with the polygons. In other words: i would either like the selection to be also linked to the polygon layer, or if selecting in the polygon layer, to be able to have a query expression to choose attributes form the linked tables, like for exapmle select all parcels from owner Miller. Or show me all parcels without contracts...

Comment: I think you could just do the first step of my answer, but join the parcel table to the links table.  Then you would have a polygon for each row in the links table.  If you want all the information in one table, you can join the other 2 tables to the first join result.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Join attributes by field value` tool in QGIS.  You will run it three times.  First, set the input layer as the owner table, input layer 2 as the links table. Set table field to fid and table field 2 to owner. Set the join type to **one-to-many**. For Layer 2 field to copy, select parcel and contract. Create a temp layer.

Run the tool again.  Set the input layer as the temp layer from the first run.  Set the input layer 2 to parcels table.  Set table field to parcel, table field 2 to fid.  Set the join type to **one-to-one**. For Layer 2 field to copy, select parcel. Create a temp layer.

Run the tool again.  Set the input layer as the temp layer from the second run.  Set the input layer 2 to contracts table.  Set table field to contract, table field 2 to fid.  Set the join type to **one-to-one**. For Layer 2 field to copy, select contract. Save the output layer.

[image]